# Label of markers used in MarkerClusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

is it possible to change labels for markers used in [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html?compiled) project?
I want them to display percents instead of number of grouped markers.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be hardcoded to sum up the number of markers it is aggregating. You could try to override this method or modify the script per its license.

From the `ClusterIcon.prototype.setSums` method:

```
this.text_ = sums.text;
```

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is define your own calculator function.

See the documentation for MarkerClustererPlus here:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/docs/reference.html